# Converting M1 password hash to M2 password hash

Tags: magento2, import, migration, password, magento-1.3

I imported around 6000 customers from **Magento 1.3** to a **magento 2.2** through csv.

Of course when i try to login to magento 2 with an account from magento 1, it doesn't work probably  because of the password hash that looks like this:

> b67f0da6abeaa55560701296df7f05d7:3K

Any idea to convert the password_hash? To make it compatible with Magento 2.2?

Comment: Actually Magento 1 use MD5 format & M2 using SHA2.

Comment: You can use Data migration tool for customers migrate from M1 to M2

Comment: Say all customer to `Forgot Passwords`. and add new password.

Comment: @meri-gh Another way: You just migrate your customer with Magento migration tool and export customer from migrated Magento and import it to your current Magento 2 website.

Comment: Thank you! Will the migration tool affect the magento 1 website? Cause its on production and I don't wanna mess up with it